# Adding a new point to a graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, geopandas, networkx, geodataframe, osmnx

I am working with some points between which I need to find the shortest paths along a graph in NetworkX. I'm trying to take a point that is currently *not* on the graph and connect it to the graph, i.e., make it into a new node at the end of a new edge. This is the syntax I have so far:

```
import osmnx as ox 
 ...
for index, row in incidents.iterrows(): # incidents is the GeoDataFrame that holds my points, read from a shapefile.
      incident_xy = (row["Latitude"], row["Longitude"])
      incident_node_id = ox.get_nearest_node(graph_proj, incident_xy, method="euclidean") # returns ID of nearest node on my graph, graph_proj
      incident_node_location = nodes_proj.loc[incident_node_id]
      incident_node = tuple(incident_node_location)
      graph_proj.add_node(incident_xy)
      graph_proj.add_edge(incident_xy, incident_node)
```

The last line, however, throws an error that says, "unhashable type: 'Point'". What is the correct way to pass the two nodes to add_edge(), and is add_node() and add_edge() the way to add a point to a graph as a new node?

Comment: The error is that incident_node is a shapely Point and not a tuple of coordinates. What is `nodes_proj`in your script ?-

Comment: nodes_proj is a GeoDataFrame of the nodes in my graph, graph_proj. What is the syntax for converting a shapely Point to some format that can be passed to add_edge()?

Comment: incident_node.xy or (incident_node/x,incident_node.y)

Comment: Thanks! (incident_node.x, incident_node.y) worked.